# Get rid of Microsoft tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[microsoft](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) shouldn't exist, as it does not help find pertinent questions. I vote to get rid of it

Comment: Pithy title attempt: Close up the windows of the [Microsoft] tag

Comment: How about: Give [microsoft] the boot?

Comment: Doesn't this qualify as a manufacturer tag?

Comment: I believe it does

Comment: Yeah, Microsoft is actually the example in the Manufacturer tags question and it's already on the list.

Comment: That's why i vtc'd the question as a dupe

Comment: Should the title be changed to "Get rid of Microsoft" and the question changed to "[microsoft] shouldn't exist, as it does not help"?